# REST response trying to IMG or other filetype

Tags: c#, rest

Ive got a question I am having a case of rest response that is always string, it suppose to download content of the file, but there can be many different files, for example PNG, now if I'm getting a string in response is it possible to convert it back to PNG at the end, I tried something like:

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.data); //response content
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(array);
Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I dont think im getting base64 string from rest looks like (part of it, and if i remmebr base64 ends with 3 === and don't have any non printable chars):

�PNG\r\n\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0�\0\0\0�\b\0\0\0���\0\0\0sRGB\0���\0\0\0gAMA\0\0��\v�a\0\0\0\tpHYs\0\0t\0\0t�fx\0\0\f\aIDATx^��!x�L���Jde%�yY�D�H$�d%2��S��Hd%y�<�ӹ�B�ٝ�O�mﺔ��d����\r\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0���\a�(H|\0�\"D�WU��v������r��o@\f!��y�����K�\0�'D�O�SM�\f�����\0��Dǯ�z4�R��C�7\0��+�\0�\0Q��\0�\0Q��UU���ļO ?�������!�#J�>���|D��$>\f�|D��$>\f��7X,�?�_\v]�V�^/�=��@4$�����$:��P9

Comment: Check my edits below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are returning base 64 string from the API response, you can do something like this

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(result.data);
Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
return image;
```

Or you can save it directly to the file

```
string filePath = "Image.png";
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(result.data));
```

**EDIT 1:**

How are you returning data from your web API? You could do something like this to return byte array and then use this array directly to write to stream.

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/imagename.png");
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
Image image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
return result;
```

and on the client side you can do something like

```
var data = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
return image;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any access to server side.

Comment: Based on the sample data you have provided in the your question, looks like your API is returning the byte array. Try the client side code I have mentioned in above answer.

Comment: Aye I made some tinkering based on this code and it worked.